# imagemagick: format png issue

Tags: laravel, qr-code

I am trying to render `png` using the `imagemagick` extension installed in `Laragon`. But, it's rendering the raw code instead of png image:

```php
use PragmaRX\Google2FA\Google2FA;

$Google2FA = new Google2FA();

$Google2FA->getQRCodeUrl(
    config('app.name'), 
    'email@email.com', 
    $Google2FA->generateSecretKey()
);
```

Rendering:

```php
QrCode::format('png')->generate($qrCodeUrl)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me alot of time but I finally found the solution, here is my solution...

Instead of trying to generate the `png` image directly from the code, like this:

```
QrCode::format('png')->generate($qrCodeUrl)
```

Use the following:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{!! base64_encode(
    QrCode::format('png')->generate($qrCodeUrl)
) !!}" alt="">
```

Reference:
https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode/issues/77#issuecomment-303253933